# Can I concatentate the result of Observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Using the Hero example from angular.io:

```
/* GET heroes whose name contains search term */
searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
  if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty hero array.
    return of([]);
  }
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
    tap(x => x.length ?
       this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`) :
       this.log(`no heroes matching "${term}"`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
  );
}
```

How can I change this so that any searchable attribute of a Hero is captured with this search?  For example, suppose address is a searchable attribute, so that:

```
this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?address=${term}`)
```

works fine.

I tried this modification:

```
/* GET heroes whose name contains search term */
searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
  if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty hero array.
    return of([]);
  }
  var names = this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
    tap(x => x.length ?
       this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`) :
       this.log(`no heroes matching "${term}"`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
  );
  var addresses = this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?address=${term}`).pipe(
    tap(x => x.length ?
       this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`) :
       this.log(`no heroes matching "${term}"`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
  );
  return names + addresses;
}
```

But this doesn't work at all because the result of the http GET is an Observable, not a string.  However, the type or kind of result in each case is the same thing (a Hero), so I ought to be able to implement something like this, right?

Before you ask, I know I really ought to modify the API this function is calling to do something like this:

```
this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?searchable=${term}`)
```

where searchable is any searchable Hero attribute, but I can't modify API at this time (and I will in the future).  For now, can I implement this hack?  How can I concatenate the result of Observables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `forkJoin` operator:

```
searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
...
  return forkJoin({
     names: this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`),
     addresses: this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?address=${term}`)
  }).pipe(map(({ names, addresses}) => names.concat(addresses));
}
```

Comment: That works!  It seems like forkJoin was created just for this kind of thing.  Tell me, if you don't mind, do you know this solution because you've done thing kind of thing before?  Or, did you google and find it?  I'm very new to JavaScript/Angular, and I'm very interested in learning how to learn this stuff.

Comment: I've done quite a lot of rxjs so knew straight off that forkJoin was required but googled the syntax as I haven't used it much.